# Keep getting a Excel VBA Type Mismatch Error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a type mismatch error 13 in line 4 of the code below

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 75000
If Sheets("Scale Data").Cells(i, 5) = True Then
Sheets("Filtered Data").Rows(i).Value = Sheets("Scale Data").Rows(i).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The code worked fine yesterday, changed the data a bit and now nothing....

Can anyone help? I went through a lot of similar posts, but cannot seem to get the answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `Debug.Print` line to your loop and analyze the value (it may not be a Boolean type)

```
For i = 2 To 75000
   ' add this line
   Debug.Print Sheets("Scale Data").Cells(i, 5)

   If Sheets("Scale Data").Cells(i, 5) = True Then
   Sheets("Filtered Data").Rows(i).Value = Sheets("Scale Data").Rows(i).Value
   End If
Next i
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I added it, and it still gives me the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the value Sheets("Scale Data").Cells(i, 5) at the point it causes the error?

Comment: The point is just past 7000 - where can I see the exact value?

Comment: So, what is the last value of Sheets("Scale Data").Cells(i, 5) at this point?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. It will either be true or false

Comment: @Chane, look at the immediate window and check the value (you probably should familiarize yourself with VBA debugging technique).